# How to write conditional formula for multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Trying to figure out how to write a formula in Google Sheets that will automatically calculate a deadline for me based on priority and an established date.

I have 3 columns: Date (A), Priority (B), and Deadline (C).

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- If Priority (B) equals 1, then return A.
- If Priority (B) equals 2, then return A+3.
- If Priority (B) equals 3, then return A+7.

How in the *hell* do I write this as a *single* formula that goes into each row under column C (Deadline)?

Answer (score 2):

Nested ifs is one obvious way.

`=IF(B1=1,A1,IF(B1=2,A1+3,IF(B1=3,A1+7,0)))`

Comment: Thank you! This is the EXACT formula I needed and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Please consider "accepting" this answer as a signal to future readers. (More at [What should I do when someone answers my question](/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're working with positive integers under 30, [CHOOSE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093371) would be a way to go:

```
=CHOOSE(B1,A1,A1+3,A1+7)
```